# SQL minus with a subset of columns: possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, T1 and T2.

T1 is

```
C1 | GROUP | SECTOR
```

while T2 is

```
CODE | C1 | GROUP | SECTOR
```

I have to select rows from T2 belonging to a specific group and having code = 100. Those rows normally have to be processed, in particular have to be inserted in a table T3:

```
C1 | GROUP | SECTOR
```

However, if there is **at least one sector**, in T1 with

```
C1 > 0
```

, belonging to the same GROUP, this T2 row has to be excluded.

So, my selection query on T2 would be :

```
select C1,C2,GROUP,SECTOR from T2 where CODE=100 group by(C1,C2,GROUP,SECTOR);
 --adding C1,C2 and SECTOR to group by because I need their values...
```

And the one on T1:

```
select C1,C2,GROUP from T1 group by (C1,C2,GROUP) having C1>0
```

Now I would have to do:

```
first_selection minus second_selection
```

But, as you can see, first selection has SECTOR column while second selection has not, so I don't know how to exclude it!

Example:
T1:

```
0|A|A1
2|A|A2
0|B|B1
0|B|B2
```

T2:

```
100|A|A1
100|A|A2
100|B|B1
```

First selection on T2 gives me "A","B". Anyway in T1 you have that the sector A2 contains C1>0 (2), so A has to be excluded. "B" is fine, as every row in T1 has C1=0.

Comment: Use DISTINCT here, not GROUP BY...

Comment: Well, the result is the same in your case, but perhaps somebody later adds a column to the select list and nothing works as expected... (And if you want to make things even more complicated you can also do SELECT col1,... from t1 UNION SELECT col1,... from t1... This will also return a distinct result...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may code it nearly literally

```
select * from T2 where code = 100
and not exists (select NULL from T1 where 
                T1.group = T2.group and
                T1.c1 > 0)
```

i.e. you need all records with T2.code = 100 where NOT EXISTS a records in T1
with the same group (T1.group = T2.group)   and T1.c1 > 0.
The select NULL in the subquery may look strange and you may write instead of null e.g. 'found something'
The point is that NOT EXISTS checks only if the subquery returns some records - the value is uninteresting.

Comment: Nice it seems working! Just a little OT (in case I'll open another post). What if there is another column, c2, which is a date and I want to find columns in T1 which are between E.c2 and E.c2+1day? Is it possible to compute it?

Comment: if you want to restrict the subquery to consider not all records of the same group simple add new predicates e.g. `T2.C2 between T1.C2 and T1.C2 + 1`